# Using CMake for multi-language project in macOS

Tags: macos, makefile, compilation, cmake

I'm working on a project that contain files from the following languages `*.c`, `*.cpp`, `*.m`, `*.mm`.

In order to provide the correct file properties to each of the types above, I set variable to store the compilation flags per file type, and apply each file it's matching flags :

```
set(CPP_FLAGS "-x c++ -arch x86_64 -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++11")
set(OBJCPP_FLAGS "-x objective-c++ -std=gnu++11 -stdlib=libc++ ")
set(OBJC_FLAGS "-x objective-c -fobjc-arc")
set(C_FLAGS "-x c -arch x86_64")

function(set_src_files_according_to_language in_source_files)
    foreach(src_file ${in_source_files})
        if(${src_file} MATCHES .cpp$)
            set_source_files_properties(${src_file} PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "${CPP_FLAGS}")
        elseif(${src_file} MATCHES ".mm$")
            set_source_files_properties(${src_file} PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "${OBJCPP_FLAGS}")
        elseif(${src_file} MATCHES ".m$")
            set_source_files_properties(${SRC_FILE} PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "${OBJC_FLAGS}")
        elseif(${src_file} MATCHES ".c$")
            set_source_files_properties(${src_file} PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "${C_FLAGS}")
        endif()
    endforeach(SRC)
endfunction()
```

I wanted to get some advise about whether it's the correct way to achieve this goal?

thanks

Comment: Can you please add some information on how big your project is and to what length you are willing to go to add `objective-c` support? Or more general: What exactly is your goal (simplification, cross-platform, ...)? Just two hints: There is [CMake issue #4756: CMake needs an Objective-C equivalent of CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/4756). And officially you would add/replace flags applied to all files globally, not on source code level (like the C++ standard to use).

Comment: Hi, the number of files in my project is high (dozens from each time, and it should grow in the future so I want a solution that is also scalable). `cross platform` doesn't relevant since this project also contains `objective-c` files, so my goal is to find out if I can apply the `objective-c` configuration to all `.m` files, and so does for the other types. I know that it's possible in `c++` since we have `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` but I have't seen dedicated variable for each language.

Comment: You really should not need the `-x` flags, as the compiler frontend program should be able to pick the correct one itself. I also recommend you take some time with the [CMake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/) and read it through.

Comment: @someprogrammerdude, hi and thanks for the tip with reducing the `-x <language>` ! I'm actually new to make, perhaps you can share some other cmake tips you think should improve from my code ?